# Chocolate chip cookies: too much butter

Tags: cookies

I made a chocolate chip and snicker cookie batter. But I added double the butter not realizing what I had done I chilled the dough until the next day. The next day when I took the dough out of fridge it was hard like solid hard and I realized I had put to much butter in it.   So my question is can I double the rest of the ingredients and add to already mixed mixture after the mixture softens?   please help

Comment: Seems like it should work to me

Comment: Can you please tell us the full recipe and method for these cookies? If it uses the creaming method, you may have a difficult time doubling the recipe if the butter's already included.

Comment: 3/4 cup butter (1 1/2 sticks) unsalted butter.  3/4 cup light brown sugar, 1/4 cup granulated sugar, 1 egg, 2tsp vanilla, 2cups flour, 2tsp cornstarch, and 1tsp baking soda.    1cup snickers chopped and 1 cup semisweet chocolate chips.      I added 3   (1/2 sticks of butter) I was supposed to add 1 (1/2 a stick butter and a half).  I dnt know what to do with it now.  So i was wondering if i double the rest of ingredients it might work. but since the chocolate chips and snickers are already mix dnt know how that will work.

Comment: If I still have any hope to save this batter any assistance/advise will help.

Comment: That's just the ingredients. You need to state how the cookies should have been assembled (i.e. the whole recipe).

Answer (score 1):

The hoighty-toighty pastry chef answer would be **of course not.** Any practical cook's answer is **of course.**

It **will** be a bit different, which is why the pastry chef rejects it - *everything must always be perfect* and waste/cost are irrelevant.

It won't be a waste of ingredients, which is why practical cooks accept it.

You should probably add the sugars to the softened dough, then add egg, then the dry ingredients (previously sifted together) roughly matching the SOP of cream butter and sugar, add egg, add dry. But don't overdo the mixing, since the currently over-buttered dough already has the flour in it. That is the main reason why it's dead to the pastry chef.

Comment: Good observation about practical v. purists. If OP follows your last paragraph he/she would be well served by having the current batch at *almost room temperature,* and the ingredients to be added *at* room temp before remixing. I'm undecided if the added flour should be All Purpose Flour, or Cake Flour. (and I just noticed this is a month old Q)